# Generic iteration between collections

Tags: swift, generics, collections, type-erasure, enumerator

So I either have a dictionary or array, and rather than checking null for either and then enumerating through them separately using their own logic i am attempting to find a generic solution that regardless of the collection type iterate through its elements, something like getting their enumerator and just doing a `for(index,element) in enumerator` but keep getting yelled at by the compiler. I have tried various ways and am getting no luck, I can't seem to cast either to the type erased `AnyCollection<AnyObject>` I'm aware the question is a little vague, but that is probably because i am still trying to wrap my head around type erasure and using the Any(type) wrappers

Edit: request to add attempts, but it does not compile as I said I am having trouble with generic protocols

```
var a = AnyCollection(array!)
var d = AnyCollection(dictionary!)

let enumerator = a == nil ? d.enumerated(): a.enumerated()//compile error

for(index,element) in enumerator {

}
```

The error message:

> Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types 'EnumeratedSequence<AnyCollection<(key: String, value: AnyObject)>>' and 'EnumeratedSequence<AnyCollection<AnyObject>>'

Comment: Can you add any code from your failed attempts?

Comment: @user28434 updated and the compile error is Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types 'EnumeratedSequence<AnyCollection<(key: String, value: AnyObject)>>' and 'EnumeratedSequence<AnyCollection<AnyObject>>'

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve by doing this? Because they have different element types (`AnyObject` vs `(key: String, value: AnyObject)`) – even if you get this to work, you'll have to do some messy type-casting in your loop in order to do anything useful with the elements.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:

1. `AnyCollection` cannot be `nil`

   ```
   var a = AnyCollection(array!)
   let a = nil -> Nil cannot be assigned to type 'AnyCollection<AnyObject>'
   ```

   This is an easy fix. `a.first` can be `nil`.

<sub>resource: [AnyCollection API](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/anycollection)</sub>

2. You are using short if statement, but the types are different. You are trying to assign different types to the same variable, and that not allowed, hence the error message:

   > Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types

   ```
   let array = [AnyObject]()
   let dictionary = [String : Any]()

   var a = AnyCollection(array)
   var d = AnyCollection(dictionary)

   let enumerator = a.first == nil ? d.enumerated() : a.enumerated() -> compile error
   let enumerator = a.first == nil ? a.enumerated() : a.enumerated() -> works but useless
   ```

To solve both issues you should use:

```
if a.first == nil {
    let enumOne = d.enumerated()
} else {
    let enumOne = a.enumerated()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but its not the answer i'm looking for your if else statement  still separates  the logic of enumeration of dictionary vs array, i want it to not care what collection or enumeration type it is (if possible) so i only have one for loop

Comment: I don't think you can change the type of the variable after you declared it.